# How to predict the future trajectory position and draw a line based on the current speed and course of the aircraft in openlayers 3?

Tags: line, openlayers-3

I wanted to draw a vector line of the plane's current speed and heading to predict its future position, with a solid point added every five minutes. I didn't know how to do that.
[look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrr0b.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula using spherical geometry is given here https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html (ellipsoidal geometry would be slightly more accurate but more complex)

```
var lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(distance/radius) +
                    Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(distance/radius)*Math.cos(bearing) );
var lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(bearing)*Math.sin(distance/radius)*Math.cos(lat1),
                         Math.cos(distance/radius)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
```

OpenLayers uses 6371008.8 meters for the Earth's `radius`

`distance` would be calculated from `time*speed` in the same units